# Whether table names and db names are case sensitive in mysql binlog file

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog, binlog

I create a table as follow:

```sql
create table INTERFACE_INFO_PK_SIMPLE
(
    API_ID      VARCHAR(128) not null primary key,
    API_METHOD  VARCHAR(24),
    API_PATH    VARCHAR(1024),
    API_STATUS  VARCHAR(8),
    API_COMMENT VARCHAR(510),
    API_TYPE    VARCHAR(48)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4;
```

In my mac os the 'lower_case_table_names' is 2 and I find the table name is lowercase in binlog file.

Does the config 'lower_case_table_names' have relationship with whther table name is case sensitive in binlog file?

If use a linux os pc and set 'lower_case_table_names=0', will the table name be upper case like  'INTERFACE_INFO_PK_SIMPLE' in binlog file in my case?

Comment: You may want to [refer the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) on that.

Comment: @FaNo_FN I have read that doc, the doc doesn't say the case sensitive mechanism in binlog file.  Does parameter 'lower_case_table_names' have relaship with this parameter?

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. I did see a word _"binary"_ in there but I was wrong to assume that it has anything related to the binlog. As a confirmation, you're referring to `binlog` as in the `replication binlog`, correct? and probably thinking that if it's ok for the source (master) and replica to have different setting of `lower_case_table_names`?

Comment: @FaNo_FN A little difference. I use the command 'mysqlbinlog' to read the content in the binlog file. But I am not sure whether the table name's case sensitive setting in the binlog file have relationship with the setting 'lower_case_table_names'. I do not care what happened if the replica's lower_case_table_names setting is different from master.